# Comparing fields to allow action

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to stop the user continuing if certain criteria are not met.

I have a table with a 'Quote Status' Field and a 'Customer PO Number' field. I want to make sure if the quote status is changed to "accepted" the Customer PO Number field is completed.

I tried various ways at various points of validation (field updates and user exits).

The basic code.

```
= IIf([Quote Status] = "Accepted" And [Customer PO Number] IsNull Then 
 = MsgBox "Please complete Customer PO Number before setting Status to Accepted"
```

Answer (score 0):

checking isnull would be `IsNull(fieldName)` and your `If` is wrong too.

try this

```
If([Quote Status] = "Accepted" And nz([Customer PO Number],"") = "") Then 
    MsgBox "Please complete Customer PO Number before setting Status to Accepted"
End If
```

*Note:*
avoid having spaces in your field names.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'm am so rusty having not used access for the past 15 years.